# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo' (im using a Pillow image and still no)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit, pysimplegui

I have looked everywere and I cant find why this:

```
image= Image.open(path+'test/test_'+lookingAt+'.png')
im= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
```

gives me this error:

```
   name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, so it can be used to define class-private instance and class variables, methods, variables stored in globals, and even variables stored in instances. private to this class on instances of other classes.

> Name mangling is intended to give classes an easy way to define “private” instance variables and methods, without having to worry about instance variables defined by derived classes, or mucking with instance variables by code outside the class. Note that the mangling rules are designed mostly to avoid accidents; it still is possible for a determined soul to access or modify a variable that is considered private.

The exception maybe not happened in the code you provided.

```py
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
>>> im = Image.open('d:/01.png')
>>> image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
>>> image.__photo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '__photo'
>>> image._PhotoImage__photo
<tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x00000232139BB5B0>
```